# Advanced custom fields repeater / jcycle: unwanted random order

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, jcycle

on my portfolio i have some projects (for example http://mathieuserruys.be/art-cinema-offoff-voorjaar-2015/ ). These images are called via a ACF Repeater field, and they are put into a jcycle 2 gallery.

this is the code i use:

```
<div class="info" style='-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;'
unselectable='on'
 onselectstart='return false;' 
 onmousedown='return false;'><span id="prev">< prev</span><br>
<span id="next">next ></span><span><?php the_post(); ?><?php the_content(); ?></span></div>  
<div class="slideshow" 
data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
data-cycle-timeout=0
data-cycle-center-horz=true
data-cycle-center-vert=true
    data-cycle-next="img, #next"
data-cycle-prev="#prev"
data-cycle-swipe=true
data-cycle-loader="true"
data-cycle-manual-speed="1"

    data-cycle-caption-template="{{slideNum}}/{{slideCount}}"
>
<div class="cycle-caption"></div>
 <?php if( have_rows('images_repeat') ): ?>
<?php while( have_rows('images_repeat') ): the_row(); 

    // vars
    $image = get_sub_field('image_repeat');

    ?>


            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"/>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<script>$.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector = '.slideshow';</script>
```

I've noticed that on first load the images appear in random order. and after that, sometimes they are right, sometimes they are not. I guess it has something to do with the Jcycle loading conflicting with how the repeater works.. any tips on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery.cycle2.js is called **after** the jquery.cycle2.carousel.js and jquery.cycle2.tile.js

jquery.cycle2.js has to be available before these 2 scripts.

Comment: Thank you Ingvi for answering! Did you mean that i have to load the jquery.cycle2.js before the rest? I did so but it seems that nothing has changed

Comment: it seems to be working now, by changing `data-cycle-loader="true"` to `data-cycle-loader="wait"`

source: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/loader.php